# Angular 5: I can navigate to a module's route without including the module's path segment in the URL?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-applications, angular-router

So I built an Angular 5.2.0 app that I divided into 3 modules:

- An `admin` module, to be loaded when the user navigates to any `admin/**` route,
- A `prefect` module, to be loaded when the user navigates to any `prefect/**` route,
- An `authentication` module, to be loaded in every other case.

Each module does its own routing. For instance `/admin/student/list`
 activates the `StudentListComponent` defined within the `admin` module.

Now if I go to `/student/list`, without the `/admin` part, it will load that same `StudentListComponent`! And this can be reproduced with every route defined in the app's modules.

This is obviously not desirable behavior. Especially given that I have route guards in place to protect the `admin` and `prefect` modules and this makes it very easy to circumvent them.

Any insights appreciated. Is it a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

This is the code I have in `app.module.ts`:

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: 'app/modules/admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
    canActivate: [AdminGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'prefect',
    loadChildren: 'app/modules/prefect/prefect.module#PrefectModule',
    canActivate: [PrefectGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren:
      'app/modules/authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/login'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    AuthenticationModule,
    PrefectModule,
    AdminModule
  ],
  providers: [AdminGuard, PrefectGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And in `admin.module.ts`:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'student',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'list',
            component: StudentListComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'new',
            component: StudentEditComponent
          },
          {
            path: ':id',
            component: StudentItemComponent
          },
          {
            path: ':id/edit',
            component: StudentEditComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    // Angular Material modules...
    NavigationModule
  ],
  providers: [StudentService],
  declarations: [
    AdminComponent,
    StudentListComponent,
    StudentItemComponent,
    StudentEditComponent
  ]
})
export class AdminModule {}
```

And in `authentication.module.ts`:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthenticationComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'reset',
        component: ResetPasswordComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    FormsModule,
    // Angular Material modules...
  ],
  providers: [AuthenticationService, AdminService, StudentService],
  declarations: [
    AuthenticationComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ResetPasswordComponent
  ]
})
export class AuthenticationModule {}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of AuthenticationModule ? Also, if you go directly to /student/list without trying /admin/student/list first, does it have the same behavior ?

Comment: @Orodan I've added the code. Yes, if I go directly to the path `/student/list` it will have that behavior. Which is the strangest part since the module is supposed to be lazy loaded, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing your lazy-loaded AdminModule inside your app component here :

```
imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   BrowserAnimationsModule,
   RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
   AuthenticationModule,
   PrefectModule,
   AdminModule
],
```

so it is actually not lazy-loaded but loaded when AppModule is. So the routes of AdminModule will be accessible both from '/admin' since and the root : '/'.
Just remove it from the imports of you AppModule and it should be fine.

I created a small repo with a working example of what you're trying to achieve [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vxzgd4)

Hope that helps

Comment: Yeah, that's the solution. Weird though... I understand why the lazy-loaded benefits would go away when including these imports, however why would the router respond to routes created in the modules?

Comment: It's not because you don't lazy-load your module that you can not have some child routes inside of it. What's weird is that, because you were importing directly AdminModule, you had two routes mapping the root '/', just loaded from different modules, and it still didn't complain

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution: in `app.module.ts`, I'm importing the feature modules (`AdminModule`, etc.) and that somehow produces that effect.

I removed these imports, and problem solved.